# Serve an HTML file in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
 res.send("index.html ");});
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server Started");
```

whenever i enter my local host IP address it displays "index.html" text instead of opening index.html file

Comment: Obvious when you look at the [first example on express page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express): you are sending back the string `index.html` not the file.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to serve an HTML file, so you have to [`res.sendFile()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: you dont need '/' when using path.join